# Is extending a shell script by creating a sub-command file unique to git and can it be mimicked for other scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

I am aware that `git` allows you to place a executable file in the `bin` directory which when given the correct naming convention acts as a sub command. `bin/git-flow`, `/bin/git-fire`

`$ git flow`

`$ git fire`

Is this functionality within the git executable or can any executable be overridden by just using this file naming convention.

I have tried this with `/bin/npm-custom` and `$ npm custom` but it executes the `/bin/npm` executable rather than `/bin/npm-custom` so i'm assuming by default this doesn't work.

If this is implemented through the original command script(`git`) then can this functionality be reproduced in another way, possible by reading the commands before executing a script.

**.bash_profile**

`source ~/.check_for_subcommand_exacutables`;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in general you have to [override the precedence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62155/3645) of the current `git` command, which should be easy unless you've already done it in some way. For example, you can create a function which falls back to the original command by default:

```
git() {
    case "$1" in
        "my_subcommand")
            …
           ;;
        *)
           command git "$@"
           ;;
    esac
}
```

In the case of Git specifically, you can create **[aliases for subcommands](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/8d07493f838bace557fbf2eab8011d0bb3a8bf2f/.gitconfig#L5-L9)**, such as `st = status`

Comment: so i would just have to write a function for each executable i was looking to add a sub command for. ok thanks.

Comment: It should be `command $@` (without quotes). Otherwise word splitting won't happen

Comment: @hek2mgl No, [you really do want to use quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). `"$@"` expands to every argument, individually quoted, so it's basically *the* way to pass on arguments unaltered.

Comment: @l0b0 You are right. `$@` when inside double quotes will get handled differently than other variables inside double quotes. Never knew that, thanks!